# How can I add this function to an array without it being called immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have an array of functions that return jQuery deferred AJAX objects called `phoneAjaxCalls`. My code pushes multiple calls to a function called `newPhone` that accepts two arguments.

```
function newPhone(tlcPhone, studentsdcid) {
    //Create new email
    return $j.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/changesrecorded.white.html',
        data: tlcPhone
    });
}
```

I try to add calls to `newPhone` to `phoneAjaxCalls` with this code,

`phoneAjaxCalls.push(newPhone(tlcPhone, stagingFormPhone.studentsdcid));`

Then later in my code, I use

```
$.when.apply($j, phoneAjaxCalls).done(function () {
  //all phoneAjaxCalls MUST be complete before this code runs
  //Redirect to a different page by changing window.location
});
```

to resolve the array of jQuery deferreds.

By using breakpoints in DevTools, I have found that instead of calling `newPhone` when `$.when` is called, but when `.push` is called.

How can I add calls to `newPhone` to the `phoneAjaxCalls` array without it being called immediately?

The bug I'm seeing is that the page is getting redirected before all of the calls in `phoneAjaxCalls` can be completed.

If you'd like to see my entire codebase, it can be seen [here](https://github.com/IronCountySchoolDistrict/Student-Contacts). It's horribly messy, since it was a rushed project. Any other feedback is welcome as well, here or on Github. The file in question can be found [here](https://github.com/IronCountySchoolDistrict/Student-Contacts/blob/master/web_root/scripts/student-contacts/scchange.js).

Comment: The problem is the code is written to immediately start the ajax call, then return a promise that resolves when the data is ready.

Comment: What is the sequence of events you desire? Do you want to queue the load functions and *start* them all at some point later when you call `$.when`?

Comment: The full code calls `newPhone` 3 times, and I need those three calls to completely finish before calling the done() callback. You're correct that what I really meant was the promise objects, not the functions themselves, added to the array.

Comment: @NathanJones If you think that was a wrong question, maybe just close it or delete i

Comment: What do you mean "wrong function"

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Do we close this question which seems to be based on the false assumption there was a problem ?

Comment: @dystroy: I think the code is correct as-is. Debugging Async promises is error prone.

Comment: Instead of breakpoints, use `console.log` to display the progress. Fast Ajax calls would have result in completion while you were on the breakpoints!

Comment: @NathanJones: How do you know that that the page is getting redirected before all `phoneAjaxPromises` have been fulfilled? Because your code does indeed wait for them.

Comment: In DevTools, the POST requests are sometimes getting canceled, and at other times completing successfully, which I've seen as a symptom of mistakes in async code in the past.

Comment: You're referring to [these lines](https://github.com/IronCountySchoolDistrict/Student-Contacts/blob/master/web_root/scripts/student-contacts/scchange.js#L439)?

Comment: @Bergi yes, that's the relevant code.

Comment: @NathanJones: Hm, can't see anything obvious there either. Except for callback hell :-) It *should* work as it is afaict.

Comment: Well, like I said, it's an intermittent issue, so my conclusions on what is causing the issue may be incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: And it certainly is callback hell. I'm planning on rewriting the ajax-related code using Backbone Models soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we determined is it based on a false assumption

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
phoneAjaxCalls.push(newPhone.bind(window, tlcPhone, stagingFormPhone.studentsdcid));
```

and then change your call to `$.when` in order to really call the functions returning the needed promises:

```
$.when.apply($j, $.map(phoneAjaxCalls, $.call.bind($.call)).done(function () {
```

or, in a more readable way:

```
$.when.apply($j, $.map(phoneAjaxCalls, function(f){ return f() }).done(function () {
```

But this construct looks like a hack, do you really need to store functions instead of structured arguments or instead of executing the ajax calls as soon as possible ?

The normal way to use promises is the one you show in the question : the callback you pass to `done` *does wait* for the promises to be fullfiled.

Comment: Having read @TrueBlueAussie's comment, I don't think I need to store actual functions, just the deferreds. Perhaps my assumption that the push() call is causing an issue is incorrect.

Comment: @NathanJones yes, most often you just have to do what's shown in the doc, that is `var d1 = $.Deferred(); var d2 = $.Deferred(); $.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {`

Comment: `$.call` is a thing? Wow.

Comment: @Bergi A little hackish, yes... How would you simply get an array of the values returned by the functions in the array ?

Comment: wow, I was thinking of the deprecated jquery bind when I first read this but so happy I clicked the link you gave for it!  thats awesome!

Comment: No wait too hackish. `$.call == Function.prototype.call`? Not necessary at all. And did you really intend to map `$` (== `$().ready`) over that array of functions? Yes, that does call them, but won't work, as it returns an array of jquery objects not promises.

Comment: @Bergi Indeed it was wrong. A confusion with a construct I recently used but that isn't applicable here. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Yet somehow I still think your answer does not fix the OP's problem (if there is any), because it still does call the functions "immediately" - before the `$.when` is executed.

Comment: What ? The functions are called in the line of the `$.when`. But I'm almost convinced OP has no real problem here, that's why I suggested a closing.

Comment: I'm fine with the question being closed since it's explained incorrectly. I'm going to do more troubleshooting and post another question if needed.